# How to iterate a list of numbers through sed command in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I want to modify a specific line in my code

```
program main
...
seed=k+rank
...
end
```

and increment k by intervals of m(=96, in my example). So my implementation of the same in shell should look something like

```
for k in {1..961..96};
do sed -i "s/{seed=k+rank}/{seed=k+96+rank}/g" main.f90;
#run the program
sleep 15m;
done
```

but this changes the string seed=1+rank to seed=1+96+rank instead of writing 97+rank and would not proceed on the next iteration.

([Bash script using sed with variables in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033860/bash-script-using-sed-with-variables-in-a-for-loop)
is what I could find)

I've searched for the use of sed through a bash loop but couldn't find or figure out the command specific to my purpose.

Comment: You need to use `$k` to insert the value of the variable into the `sed` command.

Comment: Why do you have `{}` in the pattern? That's not in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, this worked:

```
for k in {1..961..96}; 
do m=$k; n=$(($k+96)); 
sed -i "s/seed=$m+rank/seed=$n+rank/g" main.f90 ;
#run main program
sleep 15m 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do the replacement in place. After the first iteration, the file won't have `k` in it any more, since `k` will have been replace. You should read from a template file and write to a different file that will be executed.

You need to use `$k` in the replacement string to get the value of the shell variable.

And you shouldn't have `{}` in the `sed` pattern or replacement.

```
for k in {1..961..96};
    do sed "s/seed=k+rank/seed=$k+rank/g" template.f90 > main.f90;
    #run the program
    sleep 15m;
done
```

Although I wonder why you don't just change the program so that it gets the value of `k` from a command-line argument or standard input. Then you won't have to modify the program for each run.

Comment: sorry but I don't get why would substituting k with $k work, I also need to increment it with 96; so I tried doing ``` sed "s/seed=$k+rank/seed=$(($k+96))+rank/g" template.f90 > main.f90 ``` which yielded in a syntax error

Comment: although I do agree getting an argument from command line would be the easier approach I now also want to figure out how to use sed correctly in this context

Comment: `{1..961..96}` increments `$k` by 96 each time through the loop.

Comment: So the first time it will be `seed=1+rank`. Then next time it will be `seed=97+rank`. And so on.